# How to start test cases starting from max_value instead of min_value for a Hypothesis strategy?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

I'm new to Hypothesis and I want to test a function which takes integer input from Hypothesis Strategy:

```
@given(strategy.integers(min_value=2, max_value=9))
def test_function(t):
    #...
```

Hypothesis tests the function starting from min_value 2 to 9.

Is there a way I could reverse this? 
I want the test cases to start with t=9 instead of t=2.

Answer (score 1):

Usually strategies choose their values randomly. So your properties aka test cases should never depend on a certain order of values.

Most of the time each invocation of the test method should be fully independent of any previous or later invocation. If the way you test requires a dependency please tell us more about what and how you’re testing so that a testing approach can be recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to find the minimum delay required for an assertion to succeed after an interface call has been made. So I want the test case to start from a max_value of time and proceed towards min_value until it starts failing. As of now, as the test case starts with min_value, it obviously fails at t=0 or t=2. Is there any way I could find the boundary value of time using strategy then?

Comment: Also, there is no dependency between test method invocations.

Comment: I think I wouldn't use Hypothesis for this purpose. I'd rather count down the delay myself and run the test method from main.

Comment: I wanted to make use of Hypothesis and property based testing in general for this purpose. So there is no other way is it?

Comment: As far as I understand you haven’t found a property yet that you could check using PBT. The test you’re describing serves to find a threshold as a candidate for a property’s invariant. This is different from coming up with an invariant that should hold and let Hypothesis find out if it’s true.That is IMO the reason for Hypothesis being not a good fit here. But maybe I got your intentions wrong?

Comment: Oh I understand it now. I had learnt from research papers that automatic test case generation is a significant part of PBT and because of this I concentrated only on that and got the concept of property in my test case wrong. Thank you so much for pointing the mistake out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> Hypothesis tests the function starting from min_value 2 to 9.

Nope, Hypothesis tests that minimal input first and then other inputs in a random order.

If the order of test cases matters, an explicit loop is a better choice than property-based testing.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I understand it better now :)